# My script that uses a raycast to deal damage over time is causing Unity to crash. Anyone know why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash

I have created a script that makes an enemy deal damage over time to a player from a raycast but it is making Unity crash once I'm in the required range for the enemy to move and deal damage. Anyone know why?

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class EnemyMove : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public Transform target;
     public Transform player;
     public float enemySpeed;
     public int moveTrigger = 1;
     public bool isAttacking;
     public int AttackTirgger;

     public float distanceFromPlayer;

     void Update()
     {
         distanceFromPlayer = Vector3.Distance(target.transform.position, player.transform.position);

         if (distanceFromPlayer <= 10 && moveTrigger == 1)
         {
             transform.LookAt(target);
             if (!isAttacking)
                 StartCoroutine(EnemyDamage());
         }
         if (distanceFromPlayer < 10 && moveTrigger == 1 && distanceFromPlayer > 3)
         {
             transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * enemySpeed * Time.deltaTime);
         }
     }

     IEnumerator EnemyDamage()
     {
         isAttacking = true;
         while (distanceFromPlayer <= 10)
         { // in range
             RaycastHit PlayerHit;
             if (Physics.Raycast(target.transform.position, target.transform.forward, out PlayerHit))
             {
                 Target target = PlayerHit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
                 if (target != null)
                 {
                     GlobalHealth.playerHealth -= 1;
                     yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
                 }
             }
         }
         isAttacking = false; // out of range
         yield return null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I wish you would try my answer of your last question, it seems odd that you marked a different question as correct and upvoted it when you are still stuck on the same problem and posting pretty much a duplicate question, theres no need to use co routines in this situation, co routines are when you want to execute something in the future, whats happening is when you are ready to deal damage you are calling a future execution many times over on each frame

Comment: Sorry I should've tried yours as well. I've used the other answers code and marked it correct because it worked for a while and then started crashing on me. I'll give yours a shot thanks. @vasmos

Comment: No problem, keep on coding!

Answer (score 1):

If I try to explain what your code does (in pseudo code) :

```
if(distance_to_target < 10)
{
 lookAt(taget)
 move_forward() //so you get closer from the target
 while(distance < 10)
 {
  do_stuff() //the stuff doesn't change distance
 }
}
```

When your distance became smaller than 10, and due to your `transform.Translate()` it stay < 10 forever, so here you have a while(true) → makes unity crash